# Why the scope of with clause is not extended to the where clause of the update statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I receive the error message "The multi-part identifier "T.stdID" could not be bound." for the following t-sql query.

If update is replaced by a select...from... where T.stdID = ..., T.stdID is 
bounded without any problem; however, it is not bounded in where part of update!

```sql
with T as
(select ID as stdID, sum(credits) as crd
from takes, course
where takes.course_id = course.course_id
group by ID)
update student
set 
    tot_cred = T.crd
where
    student.ID = T.stdID
```

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 125
The multi-part identifier "T.stdID" could not be bound.

Completion time: 2019-11-06T19:37:49.3354478+02:00

Comment: Because a cte is just an inline view. In order to access the values from the cte you need to join to the cte. You also need to stop using antiquated join syntax. The ANSI-92 syntax has been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score -1):

```sql
with T as
(select ID as stdID, sum(credits) as crd
from takes, course
where takes.course_id = course.course_id
group by ID)
update student
set 
    tot_cred = T.crd

from
    student, T

where
    student.ID = T.stdID
```

With many thanks to @Sean Lange!

Comment: Handling joins in the way that you do hasn't been the accepted approach since the ANSI-92 standard.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I read the link @Sean Lange put and I understood why this way is deprecated. However, my main issue was why T.stdID in where part of update was not identified.

Comment: I do understand that it's not the focus of your question but remember your answer is for everyone. Ideally your answer should be a model of good practice for the next person who faces the same issue.

Comment: Thank for the sensitivity @BarneyL!